# Dynamically maintain a table which has a where clause values in it.?

Tags: where-clause

I am planning to dynamically create a where clause using the values stored in an sql table. The table looks something like the below.

```
       Conjuction  Attribute  Expression   Value
                   EMP_NAME    LIKE        'Sam%'
       OR          DEPT_NO     IN          (20, 30)
       AND         SAL         >=          3000
```

Using such table I want to build a procedure/function which gives a full string of where clause dynamically which I want to use in my application.

Basically the above condition should look like below in the output.

```
(EMP_NAME LIKE 'Sam%' OR DEPT_NO IN (20, 30)) AND SAL >= 3000.
```

Can you please help me find a solution to get such output using even more complex conditions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built-in way in plain SQL, but it is easy with any procedural language *using* SQL like Python, Ruby, Java, etc.

Comment: Thank you, but is there is a way to write the same in PL/SQL procedure or function. How can we maintain the different levels for OR and AND conditions in a table.?